# Querying many values from database by mutiple column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jdbc

I have following query:

```
SELECT
  a, b, value
FROM
  table
WHERE
  a = :a AND b = :b
```

I have to select a value for N=10000+ different *(a, b)* pairs.

The most simple solution is to make N single queries, but it sucks from the performance POV. What is more optimal solution for this case?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a temporary table where you insert all those a,b pairs, and then join that temp-table with your already existing table?

Comment: @jarlh No rights to do so, unfortunately.

Comment: How are the values for (a,b) determined?  E.g. are they simply (1..n, 1..m),determined by some business process, etc?

Comment: @JBC They are read from some external system.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  a, b, value
FROM
  table
WHERE
  (a ,b) in ((a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3),(a4,b4),(a5,b5)...(an,bn))
```

Comment: INs has limit for 1000 items. Also, what would be performance of such a solution?

Comment: performance really depends on so many factors, like number of rows, indexes, partitions etc. But this query seems to be simple and with indexes on a and b it should be faster. Also I dont think the 1000 limit applies in this case as there are multiple columns (a,b).. try more than 1000 and let me know..

Answer (score 2):

As you can't create a temporary table, maybe using a CTE instead ?

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 'a1' a, 'b1' b FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 'a2' a, 'b2' b FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL SELECT 'a3' a, 'b3' b FROM DUAL
              ..
)
SELECT * FROM T JOIN cte USING (a,b)
```

I don't remember having used a 10000+ rows CTE though (probably not event in the 1000s). I don't know if this scale wells. Anyway, as about performances, without a proper index you probably can't really hope for something blazing fast.

---

*As a matter of fact, I've just tested it on Oracle XE 11g: you can use a cte with more than 10000 rows. It works. But so sloooowly ... at least on my home test system.*